# In Bigquery How iterate the records as per counter in the table with split the data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If we have input table is like this.

[image]

i need a query to get the output in this format in Bigquery

[image]

please hep me out to get the output like this in bigquery

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

`split` may be used here to split a delimited string into an array. Default delimiter is `,`, hence delimiter is omitted in the below SQL.

Please note that `desc` is a reserved word in SQL, hence I used `description` in the below SQL to avoid escape chars.

```
with test_input as (
  select 'raju' as parent, 'naveen' as child, 1 as count, 'a1' as description
  union all select 'raju', 'ravi', 2, 'a1,a2'
)

select 
  * except(description)
from
  test_input,
  unnest(split(test_input.description)) as description_new
```

Gives

[image]

[SPLIT doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split)